# How to detect an external javascript has finished rendering its dynamically-loaded HTML?

Tags: javascript

In my website (using jQuery 1.11) I must make use of an external script that renders its own HTML inside of a div I specify for it. Since it takes a considerable time, it is deferred.

For now, in order to know when its content are loaded, I created a function that after a small timeout, tries to detect the content through a `$(selector).length` call, and depending on this result, it either a) sets a longer a timeout to call itself again, or b) finds the content and sets up the `.on()`-like events I need to set up on the loaded content.

Is there a simpler way? I feel like this is over complicated. Notice:

- I can't control the external script - I guess if I could, I'd make it broadcast a "Hey, I'm ready" event, and listen for it
- The external script does not immediately load the content, so I don't think I can rely on jQuery's `.getScript()` to fire a callback setup

Comment: You could also register the event to some parent element and don't wait for the content to load, like: `$(document).on(event, selector, function(){console.log('asd')})`

Comment: You can check out [`MutationObservers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). This removes the need for a fixed timeout and will notify you of any changes to your specified parent node. [Browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=MutationObserver) looks surprisingly good.

Comment: I didn't know about those, @schroffl. Pretty interesting and they'd probably work in my case, but Quentin's answer was enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simpler way?

Not to achieve the goal you specified in the question title without doing the things you have ruled out.

You could, however, use [delegated events](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

Bind the event handler to an element you know exists before the script runs, and wait for the events to bubble up to it.

```
$("#div-I-specify-for-it").on("click", ".element-inside-div", (event) => alert("example"));
```

Comment: I was skeptical whether this approach would work with the `submit` event, but it did bubble up in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**If you can edit your external script:**
Before loading your external script, create some event handler, then when your algorithm is done, just send the expected event. All your JS code share the same `window.document`, so you can use it :

```
    window.document.addEventListener('plugin', (event) => {
      // Your script have sent the event
    })
```

Then send the event on the plugin side

```
  const event = new CustomEvent('plugin', {
    detail: {
      // Here I send the current plugin script uri, can be used if the event handler is used by several script (not your usecase) 
      sourcePath: document.currentScript.src,
    },
  })
  document.dispatchEvent(event)
```

We use [scriptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs) to load dynamically external JS file and it works well.

Comment: `[...] when your algorithm is done, just send the expected event.` But the OP is not in control of the external script.